# How to create a column for even and odd records dynamically?

Tags: teradata

I have a query in Teradata. I want to add an additional column that would be a VARCHAR.
It should say whether the selected record is even or odd

```
select id, name, CASE newColumn WHEN  --- ???
from my table
```

Like this

```
id  name     newColumn
1   asdf     odd
2   ts df    even
32  htssdf   odd
4   asdfsd   even
23  gftht    odd
```

How can I do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your example, I can't tell how you are sorting the results.  You would need to define a sort order.  Let's assume you would do it based on the `id` number.

```
SELECT id, name,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) row_id,
CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) MOD 2 = 0 THEN 'Even' ELSE 'Odd' END newColumn
FROM my table
```

The `row_id` is incrementally assigned based on the `id` field being sorted ascending. You then use the `MOD` function to determine if there's a remainder after dividing the number by a value (in this case 2).  Result would look like the following:

```
id    name      row_id    newColumn
1     asdf      1         Odd
2     ts df     2         Even
4     asdfsd    3         Odd
23    gftht     4         Even
32    htssdf    5         Odd
```

Comment: +1 THank you for replyy. I am aware of this `MOD` however, i already have the `id` column and it is not incrementally assigned. My table is exactly what it is above.

Comment: There's no way to assign odd/even to your data in SQL as there's no rule how to assign it (rows are returned in no specific order unless there's ORDER BY). Of course this might be easily calculated at the client side if it's an application you code.